# Use Photoshop from command line

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, script

Is it possible to use `Photoshop.exe` from command line for various tasks, such as export PSD files?

(I know it's possible [with third party tools](https://www.techbuzzonline.com/export-psd-image-command-line/) such as ImageMagick, but here I'm asking specifically about `Photoshop.exe`)

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
Phtoshop.exe myfile.psd --export=myfile.png

Phtoshop.exe myfile.psd --export=myfile.jpg

Phtoshop.exe myfile.psd --export=myfile.jpg --resize=600x600,bicubic
```

What options are available via command line?

Note: I've tested `Photoshop.exe -h`, `Photoshop.exe --help`, `Photoshop.exe /?`, `Photoshop.exe /h`, but none of them worked.

(Goal: to be able to automate things for hundreds of images, scripting, etc. not from inside Photoshop, but directly from command line.)

Comment: Imagemagick is not in any way related to photoshop.

Comment: @joojaa Yes that's why I mentioned "third party" tools.

Comment: yes but even photoshop is a third party tool, i mean at least imagemagic comes installed on select operating systems out of the box. Meaning that photoshop is way more third party software than imagemagic is. In conjunction to talking about phostoshop a script or a plug-in would be a third party tool.

Comment: It seems clear enough that the question is about Photoshop and *only* Photoshop. Caviling about what does/doesn't constitute a third-party tool isn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not possible via command line with `Photoshop.exe`.

A possible solution is to use Photoshop via a Python script. As an example, this exports any PSD file into a JPG (resized to a width of 1000 pixels):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

infile = "test.psd"
outfile1 = infile[:-4] + "_export.jpg"

app = Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
app.Open(infile)
app.Preferences.RulerUnits = 1  # pixels
doc = app.Application.ActiveDocument
options = Dispatch('Photoshop.ExportOptionsSaveForWeb')  
options.Format = 6   # JPG  
options.Quality = 80
doc.ResizeImage(1000)
doc.Export(ExportIn=outfile1, ExportAs=2, Options=options)
doc.Close(Saving=2)  # 2 = psDoNotSaveChanges
app.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to write a script wrapper then sure why not. But using the executable for  like this makes little sense for the sheer time it takes to start the program to a state that does abdolutely nothing. So you are better of starting photoshop into the bacground and use it as a server (then its speedy enough)